# Flipping bitmap Function in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, gdi+

as a Practice I tried flipping a bitmap with unsafe code and pointers in C#
but **the problem is** I get the original bitmap as the result instead of flipped bitmap , it seems that the function does nothing at all , so I'm wondering what's wrong in my code !

please keep in mind that I want to flip `pictureBox1.Image` and set it as `pictureBox2.Image`

```
    private bool Flip_H()
    {
        try
        {
            b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            bmdata = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            int offset = bmdata.Stride - b.Width * 3;
            byte back_up;
            int BGRwidth = b.Width * 3;
            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)bmdata.Scan0;
                for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < BGRwidth / 2; x += 3)
                    {
                        back_up = p[x];
                        p[x] = p[BGRwidth - x - 3];
                        p[BGRwidth - x - 1] = back_up;
                        back_up = p[x + 1];
                        p[x + 1] = p[BGRwidth - x - 2];
                        p[BGRwidth - x - 2] = back_up;
                        back_up = p[x + 2];
                        p[x + 2] = p[BGRwidth - x - 1];
                    }
                    p += offset;
                }
            }
            b.UnlockBits(bmdata);
            pictureBox2.Image = b;
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have already done this with `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` functions , but as you know they are too slow , so I'm trying to Improve my code with pointers !

**the Problem was `Offset` Parameter  ! thanks everyone who helped**

Comment: Mind telling us what is wrong first? Please explain what _is_ happening that you are not expecting. Errors and exceptions too, if you are getting any.

Comment: What is wrong with `RotateFlip`? Is that too slow for you? Are you running this code repeatedly in a loop?

Comment: no , the purpose is not flipping , I want to know pointers and unsafe codes in c# better , so I tried to flip a bitmap ! and I need Pointers for Image Processing in future :)

Comment: Should this be on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) then?

Comment: Your code actually is working...it's just working with the first scan line. If you look at the very top of `picturebox2`, you should see a reversed line (this might depend on whether or not `b.Height` is even or odd--I haven't checked).

Comment: @Kenneth K , thank you too , the problem was exactly the offset !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you never advanced in the Y direction. You always change the pixels only on the first scanline and therefore the rest does not change. This happens because you do `p += offset` but you defined `offset` as:

```
int offset = bmdata.Stride - b.Width * 3;
```

You should instead define offset as:

```
 int offset = bmdata.Stride;
```

Since you want to add the stride width, in bytes, to get to the next scan line.

---

Also there is a bug in your swapping code. You have:

```
back_up = p[x + 0];
p[x + 0] = p[BGRwidth - x - 3];
p[BGRwidth - x - 1] = back_up;  // Error!

back_up = p[x + 1];
p[x + 1] = p[BGRwidth - x - 2];
p[BGRwidth - x - 2] = back_up;

back_up = p[x + 2];
p[x + 2] = p[BGRwidth - x - 1];
    // Missing!
```

You should have:

```
back_up = p[x + 0];
p[x + 0] = p[BGRwidth - x - 3];
p[BGRwidth - x - 3] = back_up;

back_up = p[x + 1];
p[x + 1] = p[BGRwidth - x - 2];
p[BGRwidth - x - 2] = back_up;

back_up = p[x + 2];
p[x + 2] = p[BGRwidth - x - 1];
p[BGRwidth - x - 1] = back_up;
```

Comment: I thought that at first, but I think that's what the purpose of `p += offset;` is. Perhaps he needs to check that `offset` is not zero.

Comment: what about " p += offset; " ? Isn't it changing the y direction ?

Comment: @Dotrix Yes it is, and your `offset` is wrong. By subtracting the width of the image times the number of bytes per pixel, you effectively reduced `offset` to 0 or near 0.

Comment: thanks , I changed it but now I get something else instead :D  , and also thanks for the other bug ! :)

Comment: @Dotrix If your colors are off or strange, take a look at the PixelFormat you're using. You use 24-bit RGB but most images are 32-bit ARGB. You might consider using the pixel format of the source image instead, but this will make your code a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Virtlink Thanks body , The function is working fine now , I'll keep that in mind too , thanks again